# Save summary count data

Tags: .net, sql-server, datagridview

I have a SQL Server table with a large amount of data.

All my data changes every 3 hours. So I want to make these variables update when my data changes.

```
Person
(
    "Name" VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    "Address" VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    "Jobs" VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    "Date_of_subscription" DATE
)
```

I want to provide the count of people that subscribed the last week, the count of people that subscribed the last month, and the count of people that subscribed the last 3 months to my web app.

Is there anyway I can save the count of my selection in a variable in my SQL Server database to avoid the waiting time. And serve the counting values to the web app without making my app counting each selection.

Can a SQL Server stored procedure help me?

I'm preparing a project for my graduation. I'm developing an ASP.NET web app and using the asp data gridview. I'm using SQL Server 2019.

My application is a dashboard.

Comment: You can create a caching table with your summary data which is updated every 3 hours after your new data is uploaded. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Thank you Dale for answering. I want to avoid the effort for my web app to run many select and count especially that I have a large amount of data. Looping through them in the app will result to slowness. I wanted to provide directly the counting values from the SQL server. Is this possible?

Comment: Sure, you write a `select` query which counts up what you want. You'd need to provide the database table definition in order to help you.